Finding a story: Space travel in canoes, automated self-healing houses
I read a book in the early 1990's or late '80s about a ML who lived in a house that could rebuild itself to a certain point.  I think his ex-girlfriend died and her conscience was became a part of weather control.  He also traveled in space with Native Americans in canoes while chanting created a bubble around them.

Warpath by Tony Daniel.

Long before Columbus, a tribe of Mississippi Indians discovered the metaphysical effect that makes space travel possible and paddled their birchbark canoes to distant worlds light-years from Earth. Now an interstellar Indian nation, armed with spears and guided missile, comes into conflict with colonists from a technological civilization so advanced that even their homes and newspapers possess artificial intelligences. History seems poised to repeat itself, but on a galactic scale.
And on the icy planet Candle, only one lonely man stands between the universe and an endless... Warpath!

The male lead is Will James and the weather system AI is Sarah:

Sarah is the-name of our weather algorithm, though only I and a few others call her that. This wind sure as hell wasn’t Sarah. How was I so sure? I don’t tell many people this, but I knew Sarah a long, long time ago, when she was a farm girl from Oregon. So I knew that this wind wasn’t Sarah in one of her friskier moods. Too mean-spirited. Instead, it felt more like a bug in the system. Or, what I was really afraid of, like a programmed assault on Thomas Fall.

The powering the canoes by chanting is described as:

Sure, the Indians could travel without chocalacas, in a two-man canoe, with one man keeping up a ritual chant about the canoe’s and its passengers’ existence, and the other doing the mental work of forging ahead. That was how they got offEarth in the first place, according to legend.


Awesome. Thank you.

@JasonSemans If this is the correct book please click on the tick mark to the left of my answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks :-)
